# Swift How to fetch user with userID

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I´m new to Swift or rather the whole programming world and I´m trying to learn how to program in Swift.
I got a table view with cells (VC1) which contain different information provided by a user. I want to click on a cell to get to a new VC by segue. This new VC should display the user information of the user who posted the information. I´m passing the userID from VC1 to VC2 by segue.
In VC2 I want to download the user information using the userID.

I´m using a UserModel

```
import Foundation

class UserModel {

    var username: String?
    var email: String?
    var profilImageUrl: String
    var birthdayDate: String?
    var gender: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        username = dictionary["username"] as? String
        email = dictionary["email"] as? String
        profilImageUrl = dictionary["profilImageURL"] as? String ?? ""
        birthdayDate = dictionary["Geburtsdatum"] as? String
        gender = dictionary["gender"] as? String
    }
}
```

Passing the userID VC1 -> VC2 works, I checked it using the print command

My Code from VC2:

```
//MARK: - Outlets

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

//MARK: Var/ Let

var event: EventModel?
var users = [UserModel]()


var user: UserModel?{
    didSet {
        guard let _username = user?.username else {return}
        nameLabel.text = _username
    }
}

func loadUserDeatails(){
    guard let userID = event?.uid else {return}
    fetchUser(uid: userID)
}

func fetchUser(uid: String) {
    let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid)
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {return}
        let newUser = UserModel(dictionary: dic)
        self.users.append(newUser)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadUserDeatails()
    print(users)
}
```

the nameLabel is empty as well as the array(users) which I tried to print in ViewDidLoad.
Var "dic" is containing the user details I downloaded with "guard let userID = event?.uid" so I guess that should be right.
Hopefully someone can help me :)

Comment: You are appending to the `users` array, which doesn’t update your UI. Changing `self.users.append(newUser)` to `self.user = newUser` should do the trick.

Comment: If you print users in viewDidLoad it will always be empty because your Firebase call has not finished downloading data yet.

Comment: @Losiowaty That works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `event` is doing, but one approach is:

**In VC1:** 
In prepareforsegue, once you get the reference of VC2,

```
let vc2 = segue.destination as! VC2
vc2.userId = "<USER_ID>" // Pass userId to VC2
```

**In VC2:** `didSet` of `var userId` would do the fetch, then assign username to `nameLabel.text` directly.

```
var userId: String? {
        didSet {
            // Do the fetch user details here
            guard let userId = userId else {return}
            let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID)
            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {return}
                let newUser = UserModel(dictionary: dic)

                // Once your get user detail data, set the label text
                nameLabel.text = newUser["username"] ?? ""
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Try the following, it might work.

```
var user: UserModel?{
    didSet {
        guard let _username = user?.username else {return}

        guard let userID = event?.uid else {return}

        let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID)
        userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {return}
            let newUser = UserModel(dictionary: dic)
            nameLabel.text = newUser["username"] ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I will test it later and will report if it works :)